# What is the usage of TARGETDIR and INSTALLDIR in WiX?

Tags: wix

In legacy Visual Studio Deployment Project installers, passing a command-line parameter that specified a value for `TARGETDIR` allowed me to override the default installation location (most of my installations take place without user interaction, so command-line automation is used heavily). However, the impression I'm getting is that WiX (by default) uses `TARGETDIR` for something different. While I can (and will) update our command-line tools to change the parameter name, that still leaves all of our existing installations that would need to be touched manually (a non-trivial effort).

**Is there any way to override the installation location in a WiX package by specifying `TARGETDIR` without breaking anything?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921078/wix-toolset-create-directory-in-root-disk-system-disk-or-c-and-copy-files-i

this worked for me. Using the "anotherlocation"

Answer (score 29, accepted):

After doing more digging, it looks like my previous experience is a result of behavior specific to VSDPROJ's (and possibly InstallShield), wheras WiX is conforming to the Windows Installer.

As I discovered at [this link](http://www.mail-archive.com/wix-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg06706.html), `TARGETDIR` is actually supposed to represent the root of the drive with the most free space available (assuming there's more than one). That's why WiX projects have directories nested under there for Program Files, etc. Visual Studio actually adds a custom action that overrides this property to the full installation path.

I was able to accomplish what I wanted by doing two things:

1. Change all of my components and component groups to install to `TARGETDIR` instead of `INSTALLFOLDER` (the default directory that WiX put in there)
2. Add a custom action that sets the value of the `TARGETDIR` property to the installation path, assuming one wasn't passed in from the command line.

To do that, I added this under the `<Product>` tag:

```
<CustomAction Id="SetTARGETDIR" Property="TARGETDIR" 
              Value="[ProgramFilesFolder][Manufacturer]\[ProductName]" 
              Execute="firstSequence" />
```

And this within the `<InstallExecuteSequence>` tag:

```
<Custom Action="SetTARGETDIR" Before="CostFinalize">TARGETDIR=""</Custom>
```

Comment: This solved my issue around this very topic! Thank you so much for sharing it.

Comment: This doesn't do anything for me... It still installs my stuff in E.

Comment: @WtFudgE: Your best bet would be to post another question.

Comment: From Wix 3.x on I would write this like `<SetProperty Id="TARGETDIR" Value="[ProgramFilesFolder][Manufacturer]\[ProductName]" Sequence="first" Before="CostFinalize">NOT Installed AND NOT TARGETDIR</SetProperty>`. Note that I added `NOT Installed` to the condition, because installation directories should only be changed on first install. In maintenance mode, Windows Installer will set directory properties to the actual install paths which shouldn't be changed.

Comment: This WiX software is so obscure and so badly documented. Without Stack Overflow it's impossible to use it.

Comment: This is working for command line, but causing issues in UI installation. Also this appears as a hack. Seems not a recommended Wix solution.