# How does WiX IISMain get set?

Tags: wix

My installers use IISMain to install to the typicall IIS folder structure:

```
<Fragment>
  <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
    <Directory Id="IISMain" Name="inetpub">
```

When there is only a `C:\` drive, this installs to `C:\inetpub\`.  However, we recently added an `E:\` drive and created an `Inetpub` folder on it.  We did not make any changes to the system beyond this - all we did was add the `E:\` drive and use typical `New Folder` functionality to create the new `Inetpub` folder.  However, my installers now install to the new `E:\Inetpub\` folder.

While this is the desired functionality for the installer, I am confused as to how `IISMain` knows to point to the new folder instead of the original folder.  How does the `IISMain` directory path get set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TARGETDIR` is a Windows Installer folder that will end up pointing to the root of the largest (most free space) drive on the machine. So if `E:\` is larger than `C:\` then `TARGETDIR` will be `E:\`.

Comment: When you say "largest," do you mean "with the most space" or "with the most free space?"  The `E` drive is about 2 MB smaller than the `C` drive but has much more free space.

Comment: Looks like [it's the drive with the most free space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11003825/128217).  Well crap - that seems unsafe - it could change over time.  How do you make it stable?

Comment: Once installed, the Components won't switch directories. Upgrade may pick a new drive though. What do you want the picking algorithm to be?

Comment: So, we uninstall and reinstall to update (haven't played with the upgrade functionality yet).  I would want it to go to the default IIS drive.