# How can you set an installer to install to the default IIS directory?

Tags: wix

So, this is a followup to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16201017/how-does-wix-iismain-get-set).  It appears that `TARGETDIR` defaults to the drive with the most free space.  How can I get a directory structure to be based in the default IIS directory (regardless of the drive on which that resides)?

```
<Fragment>
  <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
    <Directory Id="IISMain" Name="inetpub">
```

Answer (score 2):

First you have to figure out where IIS expects its default folder to be. I'm not sure that is officially documented anywhere. If it, use that documentation to define it.

If we're just guessing, then I'd guess that it's the `inetpub` folder on the `WindowsVolume`. To implement that guess, I'd use your directory tree then do something like:

```
<SetDirectory Id='IISMain' Value='[WindowsVolume]\inetpub' />
```

Again, that's just a guess because I've never found documentation that says where IIS default folder is. If you find the documentation, use that definition instead.

Comment: It looks like the default site gets setup to go to `%SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot`, so I suppose I want the installer to go to `%SystemDrive%\inetpub`.  Is that what `[WindowsVolume]` will do?