# How to specify an installation directory path in Wix Installer

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, wix

```
<Directory Id="C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Autodesk\Revit\Addins\2019">
<Directory Id="IFOLDER" Name="App Name" />
</Directory>
```

This one doesn't work either:

`Directory Id="C_Users_Admin_AppData_Roaming_Autodesk_Revit_Addins_2019"`

Comment: [Does this help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003336/what-is-the-usage-of-targetdir-and-installdir-in-wix) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921078/wix-toolset-create-directory-in-root-disk-system-disk-or-c-and-copy-files-i).

Answer (score 1):

You have to build the directory xml-style:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="AppDataFolder">
    <Directory Id="DIR_Autodesk" Name="Autodesk">
      <Directory Id="DIR_Revit" Name="Revit">
        <Directory Id="DIR_Addins" Name="Addins">
          <Directory Id="DIR_2019" Name="2019">
            <Directory Id="IFOLDER" Name="App Name" />
          </Directory>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
</Directory>
```